# Best way to create new branch copied from old one?

Tags: git, branch, upstream-branch

Suppose I want to create a brand-new branch that's an exact copy of an existing one.  (If it matters, later I'll explain my particular motivation.)

The first time I needed to do this, I did it "by hand":

```
git checkout oldbranch
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Later I discovered the "official" way:

```
git branch -c oldbranch newbranch
```

But I just discovered a pretty serious problem: using `branch -c`, and if `oldbranch` was a remote-tracking branch, *`newbranch` is not really a brand-new branch*, in that it inherits `oldbranch`'s upstream.  This almost caused me some serious problems just now, and I spent a fair amount of time trying to untangle it.

So what's the right way to do this?  Should I be using my original, "by hand" method?  Or should I remember, any time I use `branch -c`, to then use `git branch --unset-upstream` (I think that's right) to remove the upstream tracking?

The context this comes up in is that I had to rebase a branch, but I didn't really want to rebase the branch; instead I wanted to rebase a copy of the branch.  I wanted to keep the old, un-rebased branch around, partly on general (i.e. packratty) principles, partly because the un-rebased branch already had an upstream, which I obviously didn't want to upset.

When I went to push the rebased copy to my upstream, I expected git to complain that there was no upstream branch, and to remind me to do the `--set-upstream` thing. But instead it complained that things were out of sync, and that's when I discovered that the new copy retained the original branch's upstream.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

I *suspect* you may want to set `branch.autoSetupMerge` to `false`, i.e., `git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge false`.  (The connection here is obvious, no? )  At least, though, you want to stop using `--copy` aka `-c`.

## Long

> Suppose I want to create a brand-new branch that's an exact copy of an existing one. (If it matters, later I'll explain my particular motivation.)

The motivation *does* matter somewhat, but perhaps not as much as you think:

> using `git branch -c`, [when] `oldbranch` [is] a remote-tracking branch, *`newbranch` is not really a brand-new branch*, in that it inherits `oldbranch`'s upstream ...

This isn't quite right.  Instead, all the branch creation methods *can* "set an upstream" on the new branch.  Whether and when they *do* set an upstream depends on numerous options, which makes describing this tricky.  In this particular case, when `oldbranch` is a *remote-tracking name* (my term for it: see below), the *default* is that `oldbranch` becomes the upstream.  That is, we don't *find* `oldbranch`'s upstream—it does not have one; only *branches* have upstreams—but instead it *is* the upstream.

To properly explain this, let me start with why I hate the official Git name for names like `origin/main`.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  This poor word *branch* now has about 6 different meanings (before breakfast?), one of them being "remote-tracking name".  But we don't *need* it to mean that at all.  If we just use the phrase *remote-tracking name*, omitting the word *branch* entirely, we have a noun phrase for names like `origin/main` that's not ambiguous and doesn't call up false associations.

"What false associations?" you might wonder, and here's where we get into the essential difference between a *branch* name and a *remote-tracking* name.  Both locate one specific commit.  Both are useful for finding multiple commits "as seen on some branch" (somewhere, in some Git repository, perhaps using the word *branch* in yet another way), although a raw commit hash is just as good for that in most senses.  (The one sense in which it isn't "just as good" is ... well, try typing in raw commit hashes all day.  They're just *hard* for humans to get right.  I cut and paste.)  But:

- You can "get on a branch".  With `git switch` or `git checkout`, giving them a branch name will—if the operation is successful—put you "on the branch".  In this attached-HEAD mode, making a *new* commit will stuff the *new* commit's hash ID into the branch name.
- A branch can have an *upstream* set.  The upstream is actually a two-part entity, consisting of a *remote name* like `origin`, and a *branch name as seen on that remote*, such as `refs/heads/main`.  Fortunately `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch branch` and `git rev-parse branch@{upstream}` let us ignore this two-part business, which largely dates back to the time when "remotes" were first being invented.
- A branch can have "rebase mode" set for `git pull`.  That is, *when on this particular branch*, `git pull` means `git pull --rebase`.  (This is separate from the global setting.)
- A *branch* name lives in `refs/heads/`: that is, the full name of `main` is `refs/heads/main`.  A *remote-tracking name* lives in the `refs/remotes/` namespace.

All of these do show up at various times, with varying frequency.  In particular `git switch` requires `--detach` when used with a remote-tracking name; `git checkout` *implies* `--detach` when used with a remote-tracking name; in both cases this puts us in "detached HEAD" mode, so that we're on *no* branch at all.

#### Branch creation options

Creating a new branch, in Git, really consists of two steps (assuming we've already determined that the name is valid and not in use), but there are third and fourth optional steps:

1. First, we must locate some commit.  We need its raw hash ID.  Any valid, existing hash ID will do *if* it's a *commit* hash ID: tree, tag, and blob hash IDs are forbidden.
2. Then we just need to create a new ref whose spelling is `refs/heads/name`.
3. **Optional:** We may request that Git set the *upstream* of this new branch to some name.  That name can be a branch name or a remote-tracking name.
4. **Optional:** We can even copy more items.

The `--track` or `-t` option, given to `git branch`, `git checkout -b`, or `git switch -c`, tells Git that it *should definitely do step 3*.  This requires that we also supply a starting point (though it's not an argument passed *to* the `-t` option); the starting point provides the hash ID for step 1 *and* the name for step 3.

(Alas, this gets more complicated starting with Git version 2.35.  Since I'm working through history, let's start with the much older history before we add the new thing.)

The `--no-track` option, given to any of these commands, tells Git that it *should definitely not do step 3*.  We can now provide a starting-point, safe in the knowledge that step 3 *won't happen*.

If we use neither `--track` nor `--no-track`, the *default* is that Git will do step three *if and only if* (a) we provide a starting point *and* (b) the starting point we provide is a remote-tracking name.

Using `git config`, however, we can alter two Git settings: `branch.autoSetupMerge` and/or `branch.autoSetupRebase`.  With `branch.autoSetupMerge` set to `always`, step 3 *will* happen *even if we use a local branch name*.  That is, step 3 is avoided only if we use a raw hash ID or something else unsuitable (or, of course, use an explicit `--no-track`).  Or, we can set it to `false`: then step 3 *never* happens.  The default (which we can also set) is `true`, which selects the "if it's a remote-tracking name" mode.

Once we've set `branch.autoSetupMerge` as desired, we can set `branch.autoSetupRebase`.  This sets whether `git pull` should mean `git pull --rebase`, and as before, it has multiple modes: `never`, `local`, `remote`, and `always`; see [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for further details.  (The more interesting thing for me is how this interacts with the new `pull.ff` setting, if it's set to something other than the default `never`.)

Once you've digested all of this, it's worth mentioning that `git switch -t` has another function.  Suppose you have a remote, such as `origin`, and it has produced a slew of remote-tracking names in your repository.  The `git switch` and `git checkout` commands have a `--guess` option (default = on, including whenever your Git is old enough to lack this as a separate option).  With this option enabled, `git checkout name` or `git switch name` will, by default, first check to see whether *`name`* exists, and if so attempt to switch to it.  But if not, *before complaining that there is no such branch name*, the command will search through your remote-tracking names.  If there's exactly one "obvious match"—for instance, if you asked to switch to the nonexistent branch `dev` and there's one `origin/dev`—then `--guess` means *create `dev` from `origin/dev`*.  The usual "tracking" (set or don't set an upstream) rules apply, per `branch.autoSetupMerge`.

But if you have *two* remotes—say, `gh1` and `gh2` for two different but related GitHub repositories—you might have a `gh1/dev` *and* a `gh2/dev` both.  Then `git switch --guess dev` doesn't know *which one to use*.  Using `git switch -t gh1/dev` will create your `dev` from your `gh1/dev` (your Git's memory of `gh1`'s `dev`).  Of course, the upstream-setup is forced on here; `git switch --no-track gh1/dev` will pull the same trick but force upstream-setting off.

Before we go on, let's make a few last observations:

- The extra argument to `git branch` or `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c`, e.g., `git branch newbr startpoint`, provides the initial hash ID to put in the new branch name.  That is, `startpoint` is parsed, as if by `git rev-parse`, for its hash ID.  But it's also parsed to see if it's a branch or remote-tracking *name* for the `branch.autoSetupMerge` purposes.

  If we give Git the string `startpoint^{}` or `startpoint^{commit}`, the resulting hash ID is that of the same commit we'd get by default, but the *string* no longer matches a branch or remote-tracking *name*, because of the suffix.  So this *automatically defeats the `autoSetupMerge` setting*.  It can be used as a one-off.
- Besides the upstream setting, a branch name can have the rebase setting, so there are actually four steps to creating a new branch, with two of them optional (optionally set an upstream, and optionally set the rebase flag).
- Besides the upstream setting, a branch name has a *reflog*.  The reflog contains a *history of hash IDs* that were stored in the branch name.  (Use `git reflog main` or `git reflog master` to dump the reflog for your `main` or `master` branch, to see these.)  The "zeroth" entry is the current value.

  Reflogs *can* be disabled (though you still have an automatic `@{0}`), but are on by default in non-bare repositories.  So you probably have reflogs for all your branch names.  Reflogs also exist for `HEAD` itself, and you can have a reflog for *every* reference.  The `core.logAllRefUpdates` setting is what controls whether new reflogs are created as needed; see [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

  Besides the upstream and reflog, every branch can have arbitrary additional settings.  There aren't any in Git *now* but there could be in the future.  For instance, you can run `git config branch.main.abc def` to set `branch.main.abc = def`: it doesn't *mean* anything, but you can *set* it.

  The `-c` option to `git branch` is the *copy* flag.  It also tells `git branch` that you're creating a new branch, of course, as it makes no sense to copy things.  But "create new branch" is the *default* action for `git branch`, if some other action isn't set.  Adding `-c` or `--copy` means *copy the reflog and all other settings* (even the ones Git doesn't know about!).  This will copy the *upstream* setting when "copying" from a local branch, since it's, well, a setting.

Now we can also describe the new `--track` flags in Git 2.35: `--track=direct` and `--track=inherit`.  The `-t` option means `--track=direct`.  When `branch.autoSetupMerge` has its default value, we only get an upstream set by default when we create a new branch using a remote-tracking name.  The remote-tracking name itself *is* the new branch's upstream.  But if we set `branch.autoSetupMerge` to `always`, we'll get an upstream set with `git branch newbr foo` *as well as* with `git branch newbr origin/foo`.  Some people disliked the fact that the upstream *for* `newbr` is now the (local) branch `foo`.  They wanted `git branch` to read `foo`'s *upstream*, and set `newbr`'s upstream to foo's upstream.

This is what `git branch --track=inherit` does.  You must spell out `--track=inherit` exactly this way.  Note that this is also what `git branch --copy` (aka `git branch -c`) does; it's just that `-c` does a bunch more stuff along the way (copying reflogs plus all settings).

#### Rebase-and-keep

> The context this comes up in is that I had to rebase a branch, but I didn't really want to rebase the branch; instead I wanted to rebase a copy of the branch. I wanted to keep the old, un-rebased branch around, partly on general (i.e. packratty) principles, partly because the un-rebased branch already had an upstream, which I obviously didn't want to upset.

I do this a lot myself.  In general, though, I keep only the *current version* upstream (or no version upstreamed), with all the old versions just in my own repository:

```
git switch somebranch        # get on it before rebasing
git branch -m somebranch.0   # rename it to somebranch.0
git switch -c somebranch     # make the new one using HEAD, no upstream
git rebase ...
```

Since I always use the *local* name (and `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c`) I never wind up with an upstream set, even with the default settings.  The next time I rebase, I rename `somebranch` to `somebranch.1`, and so on.

> When I went to push the rebased copy to my upstream, I expected git to complain that there was no upstream branch ...

As a nice side effect, when I *rename* branches like this, any existing upstream setting sticks to the old (but now renamed to .0, .1, etc) branch, which for me means I can't `git push` it because I have `push.default` set to `simple`: the name no longer matches on both sides.  Since I create the new branch from the existing branch, it has no upstream set and I can't `git push` it either.

I *could* just rely on the reflogs: if I did not rename anything at all, the reflog for `somebranch` would have in it the values that wind up in `somebranch.0`, `somebranch.1`, and so on.  But reflog entries reflect something *automatic*, rather than some deliberate decision I made.  If I'm making substantive changes, I may choose a new *name* for the branch in the first place.

Comment: Wow.  A lot to digest there.  Thanks.  But once again I am stunned at how a seemingly-simple question can have such a complicated answer.  And we may have had a miscommunication: When I said "if `oldbranch` was a remote-tracking branch", I guess I meant "if `oldbranch` *has* a remote-tracking branch".  So when you said "when `oldbranch` is a *remote-tracking name*, the *default* is that `oldbranch` becomes the upstream", were you referring to what I said, or what I meant?  Because I thought I meant that `oldbranch` was a true (local) branch

Comment: Aha! I never use `git branch -c` (aka `--copy`) and the documentation fails to mention that it *also copies the other settings* (not just the reflog). This is definitely a documentation bug.

Comment: ... and, the bug was fixed (or at least addressed) recently, and I missed the update: the documentation now says *Copy a branch, together with its **config and** reflog* (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

> So what's the right way to do this?

The right way is

```
git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch
```

or

```
git switch -c newbranch oldbranch
```

The `-c` option to `git branch` is not the official way to create a new branch that starts with the same "content state" as an existing branch - its intent is to copy *more* metadata about the branch.

Instead of `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` you can also use `git branch`, but *without* the `-c` option:

```
git branch newbranch oldbranch
```

The main reason to use checkout or switch instead, is that they land you **in** the new branch, which is typically what you want.

(off-topic maybe, I'm curious: did you mean to use `git switch -c` the whole time, when you mentioned the official way?)

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I want to create a brand-new branch that's an exact copy of an existing one.

But you don't!

If you fix this misunderstanding first, everything becomes much clearer.

What you're trying to do isn't called *copying* in the first place. It's called *branching*. A branch created from another branch (or any arbitrary commit) is just a pointer to that commit. The new branch starts out with exactly the same history as the old one, which is all you seem to want, but they can then diverge independently.

A branch is: a ref name, the ref to a particular commit, optionally an upstream, and maybe some other branch-specific config. If you don't want to copy *all* of that, then copying a branch is not what you're trying to do.

Just to be super-clear, the manual says:

```
-c, --copy
    Copy a branch, together with its config and reflog.
```

where *config* means everything related to that branch in `.git/config`, such as:

```
[branch "oldbranch"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/oldbranch
```

So what *do* you actually want? Obviously not a literal copy including an exact copy of the upstream.

Just run

```
git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch
```